# Can Markov Chain state space be continuous?

Tags: markov-chains

I looked for a formal definition of Markov chain and was confused that all definitions I found restrict chain's state space to be countable. I don't understand purpose of such a restriction and I have feeling that it does not make any sense.

So my question is: can state space of a Markov chain be continuum? And if not then why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the state transitions themselves are countable, the state cannot enter more than a countable number of different states. So perhaps no generality is gained from having an uncountable state space.

Comment: @MarkDominus As I understand this, if I'm walking along the street I'm not allowed to model this in terms of Markov chain because world coordinates are continuous rather than discrete.

Comment: I don't understand how you could model such a thing as a Markov process. What would the state transition be? You would need to have a continuous transition between states, and Markov processes are all about discrete transitions.

Comment: If I make a step and one and another and each step I'm in this or this point according to some probability distribution. Yep, I need continuous transition in this case, but it's much like Markov chain and I'm wondering whether it can be called Markov chain.

Comment: "restrict chain's state space to be uncountable" -> sounds confusing. should "to be countable"?

Comment: aren't you thinking of a Markov process, rather than a Markov Chain? "Often, the term Markov chain is used to mean a Markov process which has a discrete (finite or countable) state-space" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_process

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks, fixed this typo.

Comment: @leonbloy Looks like you've hit the spot. It was the Wikipedia article on particle filters that confused me. " Particle filters are usually used to estimate Bayesian models in which the latent variables are connected in a Markov chain — similar to a hidden Markov model (HMM), but typically where the state space of the latent variables is continuous rather than discrete" -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter

Comment: @leonbloy Now when I know that Markov chain is just a specialization of Markov process all it sounds much more reasonable. Could you repost your comment with excerpt from Wikipedia as an answer so that I could mark it?

Comment: It's quite a question where should we stop using "Markov Chain" and start using "Markov process" - see for example [this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902/tags-markov-process-and-markov-chains)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you are thinking of a *Markov process*, rather than a *Markov Chain*.
The Markov chain is usually defined as a Markov process that has a discrete (finite or countable) state space.

> "Often, the term Markov chain is used to mean a Markov process which
>   has a discrete (finite or countable) state-space" ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Introduction))

A Markov process is (usually)  a slightly more general thing, it's only required to exhibit the [Markov property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_process#Markov_property), which makes sense for uncountable states (and "time"), or more general supports. So, for example, the continuous random walk is normally considered a Markov process, but not a Markov Chain.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it can. In some quarters the "chain" in Markov chain refers to the discreteness of the time parameter. (A notable exception is the work of K.L. Chung.)  The evolution in time of a Markov chain $(X_0,X_1,X_2,\ldots)$ taking values in a measurable state space $(E, {\mathcal E})$ is governed by a one-step transition kernel $P(x,A)$, $x\in E$, $A\in{\mathcal E}$:
$$
{\bf P}[ X_{n+1}\in A|X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_n] = P(X_n,A).
$$
Two fine references for the subject are *Markov Chains* by D. Revuz and *Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability* by S. Meyn and R. Tweedie.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it seems to be too complicated for me. I can't understand all that sigma-algebras =)
Thanks for refs too.